# Lingering package dependencies in xcode that were removed

Tags: swift, xcode, package, dependencies

When started a project in xcode, I added a Firebase package dependency through Swift Package Manager. I later removed it from the project package dependencies. However, since then, under the source control navigator, those package dependencies still show up under repositories. Is there a way to remove those?[image: Repositories][image: No package dependencies]

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this. Have you found a way yet?

Comment: Yeah, I think it uses some sort of caching system. When I added a different dependencies to the project, it removed all the old, unused dependencies. I’m not sure how to solve the problem without adding a new dependency though